# Return multiple types from Google Places Text Search request

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, google-api

I am trying to return all food establishments relating to the users text input, however I am aware that Googles Text Search request will only allow for one type to be specified (i.e restaurant). I want to be able to return all results of the following types: [restaurant, cafe, meal_delivery, meal_takeaway]. Furthermore, I do not want to use Nearby Text request due to the radius limit of 50km.

I was wondering if there was a method to return results of more than one type apart from making duplicate API calls with a different type specified.

Below is a snippet of my code making the API request with only one type specified.

```
String baseURL =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json';
    String type = 'restaurant';
    int radius = 8000;

    String request =
        '$baseURL?input=$input&key=$RESTAURANT_API_KEY&query=$input&inputtype=textquery&type=$type&radius=?$radius&sessiontoken=$_sessionToken';
    Response response = await Dio().get(request);

    final textPredictions = response.data['results'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution was to return all establishment types and then check the json result if the types field contains "food"

```
String baseURL =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json';
    int radius = 8000;

        String request =
        '$baseURL?input=$input&key=$RESTAURANT_API_KEY&query=$input&inputtype=textquery&radius=?$radius&sessiontoken=$_sessionToken';
    Response response = await Dio().get(request);

    final textPredictions = response.data['results'];

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      String placeId = textPredictions[i]['place_id'];
      if (textPredictions[i]['types'].toString().contains('food')) {
        _textSearchResults.add(placeId);
      }
    }
```